# Calling existing method to create new instances

Tags: methods, constructor, prototype

Need direction on how to code for the three instances to then assign values to the variables using isWarmBlooded method ..

````
```Animal.prototype.isWarmBlooded = function(species){

  if(this.species === "Fish"){
    return this.species = false;
  }
  if(this.species === "Monkey" || this.species === "Bird"){
    return this.species = true;
  }
  if(this.species !== "Fish" || this.species !== "Monkey" ||     this.species !== "Bird"){
    return "Could not determine if warm-blooded";
  }
 };
//Call the isWarmBlooded method on three Animal instances
//and assign the values to each variable below.
var warmBloodedAnimal = Animal.prototype.isWarmBlooded("Monkey");
var coldBloodedAnimal;
var notWarmOrColdAnimal;```
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Animal = function (species){
  this.species = species;
}; 

Animal.prototype.isWarmBlooded = function(species){ 
  if (this.species === "Fish"){ 
   return false; 
  }
  else if(this.species === "Monkey" || this.species === "Bird"){  
   return true; 
  }
  else{
   return "Could not determine if warm-blooded"; 
  }
}; 

var warmBloodedAnimal = new Animal("Monkey");
console.log(warmBloodedAnimal.isWarmBlooded());
```

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin Ye! I was able to re-factor a bunch of my code, thank you. For the new instances, tests still not passing .. seems to want a boolean for the answers ```var warmBloodedAnimal = new Animal("Monkey");``` getting a "Error: expected { species: 'Monkey', gender: undefined } to equal true" I also had to keep the original ```var = warmBloodedAnimal``` as is, was leading to undefined

Comment: @gmatsushima, can you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: sure @Kelvin Ye .. this is what I currently have ..```var Animal = function(species, gender){  
  this.species = species;  
  this.gender = gender;  
};  Animal.prototype.isWarmBlooded = function(species){  

  if(this.species === "Fish"){  
    this.species = false;  
  }else if(this.species === "Monkey" || this.species === "Bird"){  
    this.species = true;  
  }else{  
    return "Could not determine if warm-blooded";  
  }
  return this.species;  
 };  var warmBloodedAnimal = new Animal("Monkey");```

Comment: sorry in advance for layout, I tried to apply line breaks with two spaces after each line?

Comment: @gmatsushima, I have updated the code. But be honest, I am still not very clear about what you intend to do.

Comment: trying to create three instances for the Animal constructor using the the isWarmBlooded method, but it returns a boolean vs new Animal obj? which lead me to this ```var coldBloodedAnimal = Animal.prototype.isWarmBlooded("Fish");``` but incorrectly returning 'Could not determine ...' vs false ..

Comment: @gmatsushima, I think your requirement is a bit confused, it consists of two part: create an instance and call isWarmBlooded function. You can use the new Aminal() to create an instance of Animal. As isWarmBlooded is one of the function in its prototype, it can be called by this instance. As a common sense, the function isWarmBlooded should definitely return a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin Ye you were spot on with the 'two part' thought .. needed the following and it now works. Thank you!! ```var Monkey = new Animal("Monkey");
var warmBloodedAnimal = Monkey.isWarmBlooded();

var Fish = new Animal("Fish");
var coldBloodedAnimal = Fish.isWarmBlooded();

var Banana = new Animal("Banana");
var notWarmOrColdAnimal = Banana.isWarmBlooded();```